# Using a for loop in a batch file to apply a command to just the first level down of subdirectories

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, dos

I have a directory with a large number of subdirectories where I'd like to apply a command to each of them (a command that creates further subdirectories within them) my question is how would I formulate a FOR loop so that it would apply that command to each of those directories without it applying it further down into the subdirectories of the subdirectories.

I'm a noob at this and I've tried so many different combinations of this and all I get it to do is to run the command on the current working directory rather than it's subdirectories.

Comment: Go ahead and your question to show an example of what didn't work. Also show what results you expected vs. what you got. This sounds like a really simple problem to solve, once your requirements are clear.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear if you want to process the child folders, or the grand-child folders. Either way, you are going to want to use FOR /D .

To process the child folders:

```
@echo off
setlocal

::The following sets the root to the current directory.
::But root could be set to any path you choose
set "root=."

pushd "%root%"
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  rem %%F now contains a child folder.
  rem You could make a subdirectory easily enough
  md "%%F\newFolder"
)
```

To process the grandchild folders:

```
@echo off
setlocal

::The following sets the root to the current directory.
::But root could be set to any path you choose
set "root=."

pushd "%root%"
for /d %%A in (*) do (
  rem %%A now contains a child folder.
  pushd "%%A"
  for /d %%B in (*) do (
    rem %%B now contains a grandchild folder
    rem You can easily create a new folder
    md "%%B\newFolder"
  )
  popd
)
```